# A way to see a mesh in object mode while editing UVs?

Tags: mesh, uv

I have to adjust some UVs positions and I want to see the effect immediately on the mesh.
But when I edit UV map, I'm in edit mode and the vertices are selected (all is covered by the yellow part due to the selection)... so I cannot see clearly the impact of what I do directly on the mesh.

How to avoid that? Is it possible to see the mesh in object mode while editing the UV map?

[image: Problematic UV]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this helps, you can change the color & transparency of that editing mode, adjusting it to let you see what's below.

See in User preferences Themes settings

[image]

If it's a temporary change, just don't save user preferences, and it will be reset at next program start, or new file.

**Edit:**
I'm adding a screenshot of the alternative setup I suggested in the comments:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for faces, but i found no alpha for the vertices and edges. An exemple of what i want to fix (the seam lines here) : https://i.gyazo.com/394fc3deb2a84ace2d7a014aac1bcc0b.png

Comment: yes, but how could you fix positions for invisible vertices? You can try adjusting their colors in order to have the least impact for the region you are editing, perhaps. Sometimes you can also try to fix the texture, to adapt to your UV map.

Comment: You could also enable realtime rendering (even in a separate window) so that while you edit the UV, you can immediately see the result clearly in the separate view. This work for cycles and internal. If you limit the render area (or framing) to just the UV area you're rendering, it should be quick.

Comment: Yes ! Thanks again. Real time rendering is the solution !